# How to hairpin a whole network segment?

Tags: networking, iptables, nat

I am trying to set up hairpinning on my home network following an [article](https://newspaint.wordpress.com/2018/09/13/hairpin-for-lxc-containers-using-iptables/) and a [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/240766/hairpinning-in-linux). My network is below, host `B` serves a few services, let's settle for SSH port `22`)

[image]

The reason for the hairpinning is typical: I have `ssh.example.com` defined on an Internet DNS and it points to my public IP (`200.200.200.200`) on port `2223`. This port is redirected to host `B` (`192.168.10.2:22`) via

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i nicWan -p tcp --dport 2223 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.2:22
```

I want to be able to reach `192.168.10.2:22` from host `A` via

```
ssh 200.200.200.200 -p 2223
```

Despite administrating Linux machines since 1994, I have never really looked closely at `iptables` because I was using [`shorewall`](https://shorewall.org/) and the briefly [`firehol`](https://firehol.org/).

My initial problem is with understanding whether hairpinning is applicable to the whole traffic "from the LAN", or do I need a rule per destination port (the references I mentioned and several others diverge, I would prefer the former).

The main issue comes from my lack of understanding of where in the `iptables` context (chains) I need to set what. I understand the reasons for the operation (very well described in the first reference), it is just that I do not know where to put it.

Specifically, how can I say in `iptables` language to NAT the packets from **any** device on `192.168.10.0/24` that want to go to `200.200.200.200`, and MASQUERADE them so that they can come back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that your interface is wrong because your traffic from host A hits your nicLan, not nicWan.

And as you said you need to masquerade so your return packages finds their way to right place. The second rule masquerades all traffic coming from your local subnet and going back to your local server.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i nicLan --destination 200.200.200.200/32 --jump DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.2
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o nicLan --source 192.168.10.0/24 --destination 192.168.10.2/32 --jump MASQUERADE
```

As you see, I didn't define any ports, so all traffic going to your public address from your LAN is DNATted to your server in the local LAN.

And don't forget to add allowing rules in your filter tables if needed.

Comment: Thank you, it works great (I just changed the case of `iptables`). Your comment about packets hitting the WAN nic was an eye-opener. I now have to solve one more issue with the fact that my SSH port on the outside is on `2223` and not `22` and translate it somehow (in the hairpinning sense, not packet forwarding that works fine)